# How to extract a Generic type from arg

Tags: java, generics

I have a method signature that looks like

```
public void (Foo<T> foo)
```

In this method I need to call a method that takes

`Class<T> clazz`

as an argument.  How can I get a reference of type `Class<T>` from foo?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to type erasure, you cannot get directly at type parameters. The information is simply not present at runtime. API that needs reference to type parameter's class needs to take class object instance...

public void abc(Foo<T> foo, Class<T> clazz)

Comment: Java 7 is supposed to be adding reified generic types with which you will be able to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your method signature is correct?

I think that without class T you cannot make argument looks like

```
public void method(Class<T> obj){
}
```

The type of argument must be present, so you already know the type of incoming.
When you change it into this:

```
public <T> void method(T u){
    System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
}
```

You should be able to get class name or just class reference, not?

Docs:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html

Comment: Yes, I inadvertently omitted the <T>.  Good suggestion, I will try that out.

Comment: let me know if that helped :) GL ;)